# Asp.net msgbox not trigeering in browser that is not of the server

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I am having problem in triggering Msgbox. It is not working in other browser than that of the iis server.
This is my code

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If (Not Session("user") = 1) Then
            MsgBox("You are not signed in!")
            Exit Sub
  End If
End Sub
```

How to resolve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide your code? Vb.net or c#?

Comment: Have you created a component in VB and using in ASP (& displaying in browser)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you say in the browser, I assume you're using WinForms or MVC, etc.  MessageBox doesn't exist in that context. Look into using Javascript or some client-side code to send a message to the user.  Something like this should be close:

```
String cstext = "You are not signed in!";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PopupScript", cstext, true);
```

or:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
```

Good luck.